# WCF logging not logging SOAP request

Tags: xml, wcf, logging, soap, system.diagnostics

I know this has been asked multiple times and i might have read them all including MSDN ones. Looks like my scenario is a bit different. I think i have setup eveything including the system.serviceModel node, system.diagnostics and the permission. But it only logs the one that says "Get configuration section". What i want is the XML that i pass (including the security headers) to the web service. It generated the svclog file so looks like i have permission (after i granted EVERYONE full access) but it only contains this:

[image]

Here's my config

```
<source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="c:\logs\Traces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
    name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
  </add>
</sharedListeners>

<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="System.ServiceModel">
    <endpoint address="<webservice url>" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="<contract name from ServiceContractAttribute>"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
  </service>
</services>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
  <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
    messageFlowTracing="true" />
</diagnostics>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Spent all day tweaking the config and the permissions. What else could i be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the below configuration recoding the server log (the principle is the same as the client side).
Because the tracing technology of WCF is based on Dotnet platform, tracing source should be configured first.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xmlLog" initializeData="myLogs.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfLogSample.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfLogSample.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

After the client invocation is completed, the server will log the communication and we need to restart IIS to check the log located in the root directory.
[image]
Here are some references, wish it is helpful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

**Updated:**
Please use my below configuration on the client side.

```
      <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xmlLog" initializeData="myLogs.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
      </diagnostics>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.70:8733/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi Abraham. Thanks for your response! I dont have access to the webservice's log. It's hosted from a 3rd party. I only created a proxy class to consume the webservice. So I'm trying to find a way to do the logging on our side while doing the request. before we send to the webservice. Also, my configuration is based from the link you posted.

Comment: The principle is the same as the client, adding the tracing source and diagnostic section in the ServiceModel section. Please try to migrate the System.diagnostics section and diagnostic section to the configuration of the client.
Besides, the trace file will be generated in the root directory of the client side.

Comment: Thanks for  your response Abraham! I have tried the config above, but it still didnt log any.I just copied the config above and supplied the endpoint address and contract. I'm using basicHttpBinding so i did not changed that. I got the contract value from the proxy i generated via svcutil in the ServiceContractAttribute.namespace + ServiceContractAttribute.configurationname. I also checked event viewer, but i dont see any except from the internal server error from the webservice which they claim that was caused by incorrect security header i passed. Which is why i want to see the entire xml

Comment: i have updated my service model node similar to your config  but still no logs. Is there anything else that i might have missed?

Comment: I have updated my reply, please use my client configuration.

Comment: Hi Abraham, I was able to make it work. I moved the config to another config within my project. But still didnt log anything until i closed my debugger. Thanks for pointing that out! :)